# What services does AWS have for AD integration and multi-account support?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are in the process of transferring what we currently have in our on-premises infrastructure to the cloud and taking advantage of what AWS has to offer. We are in the process of planning how we can make this process as smooth as possible, so one of the first things that came to mind was, What are the best possible solutions to implement what we currently have in our premises with users registered in AD and how we will be able to manage them, e.g. we create a new user in AD and automatically we can see that new user in our AWS environment so we don't have to manage them on premises as well as AWS and so they can sync?

The next question which I think the answer is Control Tower (and that's why I'm sending my question on this topic), but I would like to confirm and see if there are any other options out there that we might me missing.

As I said earlier, we are in the process of transferring our current on-site infrastructure to the cloud, so at this time we have three environments where we manage development: Development, Staging and Production. We thought of having each of them separated in their own AWS account so we can manage them individually but also we want a way to easy switch accounts between them and possibly get one consolidated bill for all of those three accounts but with the details in each account, and be able to easily make them communicate resources in one account to resources in another account. What would be the best solution for these challenges in AWS if someone can suggest best practices on these?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the AD connection, you can use the AWS AD Connector service. The official AWS blog has a tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-your-on-premises-active-directory-to-aws-using-ad-connector/

Billing for a multi-account organization is pretty straightforward, all sub-accounts pay through the root account so you won't have to worry about separation of billing.

Communicating between the environments (accounts), however, requires a bit more legwork. You can use a hub and spoke model and reach out to all environments from an individual environment, or, you can create trust relationships between roles and resources via IAM policy in different accounts and map them to one another.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jacob! I think that would work for AD, regarding connecting the three accounts, I was reading about VPC peering. Would that be a better solution?